# DropDownList not posting back, even with AutoPostBack set

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

**Obscure solution at end of post**

Using asp.net page with C# codebehind, I have successfully built and populated a DropDownList.

What I would like to do is capture a new value selected from the dropdownlist (preferrably using a postback to my codebehind). The codebehind can then update other things on the page based on this newly selected dropdownlist value.

My first attempt was to use

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="myDDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="foo"></asp:DropDownList>
```

with the C# method

```
public void foo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;
    string myValue = "";

    if (ddl != null)
    {
        myValue = ddl.SelectedValue;
        // Do some stuff
    }
}
```

This did not work. When the selected index was changed, it simply reloaded the page, but the IsPostBack flag was always false.

So I sifted through SO and tried a number of different tactics. Most recently, I tried to register the client-side onChange event in the codebehind and turned off the AutoPostBack.

in the ASP.Net page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="myDDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:DropDownList>
```

in the codebehind:

```
myDDL.Attributes.Add("onChange", "doSomeStuff(this);"); // Done on databind.
```

I added the client-side javascript to call the page's __doPostBack function

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function doSomeStuff(ddl) {
        var ddlVals = document.getElementById(ddl.id);

        __doPostBack(ddlVals, '');
    }
</script>
```

This also failed, although I thought it was going somewhere when I saw the javascript execute properly.

Looking in the codebehind, though, it's still not working. When I put a breakpoint in the Page_Load IsPostBack is false! But it's supposed to be a postback!? It was posted back using __doPostBack and (seperately) automatically with AutoPostBack="true"

So I dug deeper.

According to this MSDN article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178141(v=VS.85).aspx) based on the results on the page load I'm doing a "Server Transfer" rather than the desired Postback (IsPostBack is false, PreviousPage is, as expected, the same page that should be posting back, IsCallback is false, and IsCrossPagePosting is false).

**What could be going on to hyjack the AutoPostBack** and the __doPostBack to make it look and act like a "Server Transfer"?

**What can I set/check on the parent control**/page to make sure it's allowing postbacks?

**EDIT:**

The Page_Load looks something like:

```
private SpecialDataObject _someData;
private string foobar;
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //set some variables.
    this.foobar = "blah";

    LoadSomeUnrelatedData();

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (_someData == null)
        {
            LoadDataWithoutBinding();
        }
        BindMyData();
    }
}
```

With a breakpoint at `//set some variables` the Page.IsPostBack is always false even after AutoPostBack.

**EDIT 2:**

The answer was in the Server Transfer. In a distant control loaded from the master page, the URL is inspected and rerouted before it hits the page, effectively negating my postback. I didn't see it before because I had added the breakpoints only in the target page.

Comment: we may need to see a limited form of your Page_Load as well to help you figure out what is going on.

Comment: I added in the page_load outline, @jmein. BindMyData binds the data successfully.

Answer (score 5):

I would check to make sure that you don't have validation somewhere interfering with the postback. To check this, set `CausesValidation` to false on the DropDownList.

Answer (score 3):

Are you resetting the value of your dropdown in your PageLoad?

Also you may want to think about using an **UpdatePanel** so that it doesnt reload the whole page.

Comment: Yes it gets re-bound on page_load, but only because it's not setting IsPostBack to true when it supposedly posts back. If IsPostBack was set to true, I could avoid resetting the dropdownlist... Seems like a Catch-22 to me. Also, good point about the UpdatePanel, however I have some substantial page logic that gets executed, so in this case UpdatePanel isn't for me.

Comment: @Peach That is weird it should be setting the IsPostBack to true. However, you could probably still use an UpdatePanel even though you have such complex page logic. I have done it several times before and it makes the page much more user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Is it inside an UpdatePanel? If yes, set ChildrenAsTriggers="true"

Comment: No it isn't. UpdatePanel is not appropriate in my specific circumstance, although might be useful in general.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the attempts you've mentioned, *as well as the comments regarding the update panel*, I attempted a few things.

By setting the data source on the load event, you will only do it once:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //set up data here
    }
}
```

You may use the Page.IsPostBack code and the method of yours to get what you want:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
    //do page reload logic in here
}

protected void foo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get your selected value here
}
```

(Note: Both of the postback conditionals are in the page load event)

EDIT:

Here's the whole setup, its basic, but you get the idea:

[image]

As you can see when I made a selection from cat to dog, it recognized that there was a postback, so it skipped the databind and set t. I could only assume there's something else here that I'm not seeing if you can't get it to ever return true for you on postback.

Comment: Not sure I follow you. By "load event" do you mean Page_Load or something else? If page_load, I already do check the IsPostBack before binding the data source, but IsPostBack is always false, so it always gets rebound...

Comment: I posted a SS/clarification for you.

Comment: right, it's unfortunately that 'something else' I can't figure out :)

Comment: Depending on the security natures of sharing files, I could debug it if you wanted to send me a copy of what you have. If it's confidential you could remove all data sources/info as well, so there would be no risk involved. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the offer. I got it figured out.